# Can we create events for "n" number of office 365 accounts using one zap? (Zapier - Office365)

Tags: office365, zapier

I need help regarding zap creation in zapier.
I have been working on a meeting system and created a zapier app that will fetch all meetings from my system into office 365 calendar.

My problem is, if my client has 500 employees then all those 500 employees will have to create their own zap to sync my application with office 365 calendar.

Forexample, if I create a zap and add office 365 in to do list, then I have to provide the credentials of single office 365 account where I can send the meeting details but I want to send the meeting details to n number of office 365 accounts using same zap.

Please let me know about this solution that how can I solve this.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about web based applications, not programming. Ask on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not currently possible.